# Get HDP version through Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

We installed a new Spark version so all folders name are named similar to:

```
ls /etc/hadoop/
2.6.4.0-91  conf  conf.backup
```

and from `spark-submit` we get

```
spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91
      /_/
```

What I need is to identify the spark version - **2.6.4.0-91**. We can do:

```
ls /etc/hadoop/ | grep [0-9]
2.6.4.0-91
```

but this approach is not so good (because other folder name with number could be there, etc.)

By `spark-submit --version` we got

```
version 2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91
```

while we need only the version - **2.6.4.0-91** , ( **without 2.2.0** )

Any ides how to got the version - without (2.2.0) from `spark-submit --version`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since hadoop is installed on the linux machine,

as:

```
rpm -qa |grep hadoop | grep client
hadoop_2_6_4_0_91-client-2.7.3.2.6.4.0-91.x86_64
```

then I can use **hdp-select** command in order to get the required HDP version

```
 hdp-select |  grep hadoop-client | awk '{print $3}'
 2.6.4.0-91
```

or:

```
hdp-select | grep hadoop-client
hadoop-client - 2.6.4.0-91
```

Comment: You're grepping the Hadoop client and the **HDP version**... **not** Spark.... Why didn't you grep spark?

Comment: because the spark version integrated from <spark><hadoop>  version  , spark from CLI is --> version 2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91  , and hadoop version is the same - 2.6.4.0-91 as the second spark part , if I am wrong please correct me

Comment: Again, that's not the hadoop version. Hadoop  `2.7.3` is running on HDP `2.6.4.0-91`, which has Spark `2.2.0`

Comment: ok , my first target was to capture the version - under /etc/hadoop/  , which is the folder that represented by hadoop 2.6.4.0-91 , until now it fine , so next , I will want to capture the HDP version but not want by the approach as ls /etc/hadoop/ | grep [0-9] , so I find the option to run the hdp-select  command and by this CLI I want to capture the HDP version ,

Comment: You should be listing versions within `/usr/hdp`, not `/etc/hadoop`. And one more time, "hadoop 2.6.4.0-91" does not exist

Comment: Regarding my first comment, `hdp-select | grep spark-client` should have been done if you were interested in Spark

Comment: so you suggestion is to do -  ls /usr/hdp | grep [0-9] ?

Comment: ok ,so if you insist this is the right direction please put your answer , so all folks will be able to read it

Comment: Your answer is fine, just confusing because it has nothing to do with Spark

Comment: Only the person that posts the question can "select" an answer

Comment: Ha ... , OK because I am very Junior here ,so I need to wait 2 days ( but not problem , I can live with that ) , if you think my answer is good I will happy to get up vote -:)

Answer (score 0):

Login to the edge node and try the below command on terminal

```
$ hdp-select| grep hadoop-client
```